# How can categorize properties in a class?

Tags: c#

Assume we want to define a class that contains all constants that we will use in our solution. And this class doesn't have any methods.

```
public class _const
{
    /// Group1: 'DataBase'. We naming "db" group
    public const Server_Name = 'ServerName';
    public const DB_Name = 'DBName';
    public const DB_User = 'UserName';
    public const DB_Password = 'Password';

    /// Group2: 'Default Variable'. We naming "default" group
    public const Title= 'DefaultTitle';
    public const KeyWord = 'DefaultKeyWord';

    /// Group3: 'Status' constans.We naming "status" group
    public const Approved = 'Approved';
    public const Rejected = 'Rejected';
    public const Suspended = 'Suspended';

    /// And so on...
    /// ...
    /// ...
    /// ...
}
```

We know, these constants will be used anywhere in the solution simply with below instruction. And don't need to create an instance of the class.

```
/// For example:
string x = _const.Approved;
```

My question is: for easier use and more code readability, is there any way for grouping related constant together? And access to each group with own prefix name (like namespace)?

Something similar to the following code.

```
/// For example:
string x = _const.db.DB_Name;
string y = _const.default.KeyWord;
string z = _const.status.Approved;
```

Comment: You can do subclasses by defining inner classes in _const class. It will give you _const.Status.Approved, etc

Comment: On an (almost) unrelated note, there is zero advantage from defining a constant like "Approved" with the value "Approved". Conversely, you don't want to have something like "DB_Name" a constant, but configurable. While your question has an answer, I have never seen a project (and hope never to see a project) where constants are so plentiful that they need *levels* of organization. And grouping them all in one class is, for most software, a terrible idea. If they have natural groupings, why not use those classes on their own instead of forcing them together?

Comment: Instead of classes, you could use Structs.

Comment: @Cybrus: That would make no different for static members (which consts effectively are).

Comment: @Cybrus , can you describe more? please prepare a code sample of your idea. thank you for attention

Comment: Firstly, your code won't even compile - you've used character literals instead of string literals. I would *strongly* advise you to avoid a single `Constants` class for everything. If you really need lots of constants, group them by putting them in different classes. But it looks like at least for the status, you'd be better off using an enum...

Comment: @JeroenMostert this is a general simple sample for presenting which is in my mind.
Originally, in my solution some key word such such as 'Approval Statuses', 'Workflow Names' and ... was represent with reserved 'code ID'. this constant class stores code value of them and I want use name of them instead of 'code ID' in my code.

Comment: @M.i.T: per Jon's remark, for mapping to numeric IDs you want enums instead. If you must map to symbolic strings, list of constants can be used, but even then it makes more sense to organize these in separate classes, not as nested classes of some all-encompassing `_const` class.

Answer (score 2):

I think a mix of `Enum` and `Dictionary` could help you since, though with a little more verbose call, it assures consistency throughout your code:

```
public enum Db
{
    Server_Name,
    DB_Name,
    DB_User,
    DB_Password,
}


public enum Default
{
    Title,
    Keyword
}


public enum Status
{
    Approved,
    Rejected,
    Suspened
}

public static class _const
{
    public static Dictionary<Db, string> db = new Dictionary<Db, string>()
    {
        {Db.Server_Name, "ServerName"},
        {Db.DB_Name, "DBName"},
        {Db.DB_User, "UserName"},
        {Db.DB_Password, "Password"}

    };


    public static Dictionary<Default, string> defaults = new Dictionary<Default, string>()
    {
        {Default.Title, "DefaultTitle"},
        {Default.Keyword, "DefaultKeyWord"}
    };


    public static Dictionary<Status, string> status = new Dictionary<Status, string>()
    {
        {Status.Approved, "Approved"},
        {Status.Rejected, "Rejected"},
        {Status.Suspened, "Suspended"}
    };
}
```

that you can use in your code like:

```
string string_x = _const.db[Db.Server_Name];
string string_y = _const.defaults[Default.Keyword];
string string_z = _const.status[Status.Suspened];
```

Comment: By your answer, advantage of pure constant will be lost. In other words, class must be static or instance of class must be created. In addition, in both way, this object is runtime variable.

Comment: I concentrated on the  _"for easier use and more code readability"_ part of your question. No doubts `Enum`s makes coder and his classes users life easier and his code more readable, too. At the expense of some extra coding you set it once and use forever. But if your main issue is the use of a _pure_ constant then this is not the way

Comment: I accept your opinion. thus i vote up you comment.
I described my idea with some misunderstand. 'Pure Constant' is not my issue. Actually, I do not want create instance from class OR use run time object. At finally, I think you are right, and useing of enum is better than constant

Comment: I don't know, voting on comment hasn't reputation for user. Therefore I up voted on your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make your class static and define another nested static class like this:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static class Group1
    {
        internal const string String1 = "String1";
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    internal static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Constants.Group1.String1);
    }
}
```